# why gives it back Parsing failed?

Tags: php, json, laravel, arduino

I went to get this sample code, the arduino code works, if I put the json data in an individual file it works for example teste.json or .html but if using laravel it says: Parsing failed!
if you try the url in the browser it returns the json code.
if someone can help me thank you!!

laravel code:
route:

```
 Route::get('cartao/{key}/{UID}/{porta}', [CartoesController::class,'cartao'])->name('cartao');
```

controller:

```
    public function cartao($key,$UID,$porta){

        return response('{
"sensor": "gps",
"time": 1351824120,
"data": [
48.756080,
2.302038
]
}
', 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
}
```

arduino serial:

```
  Connecting...
Connected!
Parsing failed!
```

arduino code:

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>

void setup() {
  // Initialize Serial port
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) continue;

  // Initialize Ethernet library
  byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
  if (!Ethernet.begin(mac)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to configure Ethernet"));
    return;
  }
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println(F("Connecting..."));

  // Connect to HTTP server
  EthernetClient client;
  client.setTimeout(10000);
  if (!client.connect("pap.hyperchip.pt", 80)) {
    Serial.println(F("Connection failed"));
    return;
  }

  Serial.println(F("Connected!"));

  // Send HTTP request
  client.println(F("GET /cartao/xxxxx/arddfdfu/arddfdfdok2.json HTTP/1.1"));
  client.println(F("Host: pap.hyperchip.pt"));
  client.println(F("Connection: close"));
  if (client.println() == 0) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to send request"));
    return;
  }

  // Check HTTP status
  char status[32] = {0};
  client.readBytesUntil('\r', status, sizeof(status));
 if (strcmp(status, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK") != 0) {
    Serial.print(F("Unexpected response: "));
    Serial.println(status);
    return;
  }

  // Skip HTTP headers
  char endOfHeaders[] = "\r\n\r\n";
  if (!client.find(endOfHeaders)) {
    Serial.println(F("Invalid response"));
    return;
  }

  // Allocate JsonBuffer
  // Use arduinojson.org/assistant to compute the capacity.
  const size_t capacity = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(3) + JSON_ARRAY_SIZE(2) + 60;
  DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer(capacity);

  // Parse JSON object
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(client);
  if (!root.success()) {
    Serial.println(F("Parsing failed!"));
    return;
  }

  // Extract values
  Serial.println(F("Response:"));
  Serial.println(root["sensor"].as<char*>());
  Serial.println(root["time"].as<char*>());
  Serial.println(root["data"][0].as<char*>());
  Serial.println(root["data"][1].as<char*>());

  // Disconnect
  client.stop();
}

void loop() {
  // not used in this example
}
```

Comment: any reason to not send the content type as json?

Comment: no.. how to send as json? ...

Comment: i just meant you are sending the content type as `text/plain` instead of something like `application/json` or the likes  ... but the actual json seems fine, i was able to decode it without issue in PHP

Comment: continue return Parsing failed!.. ;(

Comment: Probably your problem is in line breaks. Try to use:


`<?php

return response()->json(['sensor' => 'gps', 'time' => 1351824120, 'data' => [48.756080, 2.302038]]);`

in Laravel controller.

Comment: I guess the response is chunked transfer encoded. Print the received json